# Achieving 1 pixel outline around sprites which changes colour depending on the background?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

Here's an example of what I mean: http://38.media.tumblr.com/aa36eac06bebe495f34046d4b2557410/tumblr_n8a8p4dkOb1s6ek46o1_500.gif

In this gif, when the character is on the dark background, his outline is almost black, whilst it retains more colour if the background he's on is the sky one. How can I achieve this in Unity? I don't think it's individual sprites

Comment: You can tell with the basic tiles for the map as well; the blocks on either side of the ladder have darker outlines when they've got the dark background

Comment: It looks like each sprite has transparency on the outline